# How run a .py (python?)-script in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, script, python

Hi I got the complete code, but I don't know how to run the script. The script is some plot of a function, can one run the script so that the plot is shown in xcode?

Comment: What do you mean with "show in Xcode"? If you want to just show the console output of the script, can you run it in Terminal instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use Xcode. Just open Terminal and run:

```
python /path/to/file.py
```

For making an Xcode project for a python script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276967/

Answer (score 1):

You must include the python you use into the xcode build scheme after that you can run python scripts in xcode.

[here](https://ericasadun.com/2016/12/04/running-python-in-xcode-step-by-step/) is the detailed explanation on how to do that.

But your only goal is to run the script and view the plot, running the code in terminal is the better option to do that.

Comment: If you need to build the python script into independent one xcode is not the option though. You can go with PyInstaller package to do that.